# Learning angularjs 1.3 , knowing that angular 2 will be released in 1 year

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to learn angularjs 1.3,but i am having some problems on making up a decision if it is the right time to do so, since angular will be be dramatically changed when the version 2 will be released.

It is worth it to spend the time and energy to learn a framework that we know it is going to change.

what suggestions can the people give me regarding this.

Could you please suggest any other framework, that is easy to learn?

Thanks!

Comment: Won't be as dramatic as you think, they won't risk alienating the existing dev base.

Comment: I just found out that they are planing to remove the controllers...  which I have just read about it

Comment: I agree, wrong place for question, but interesting. I have the same dilema.  Yes, 2.0 will be radically different, but I think its still worth looking at current versions, as some of the principles will still be valid, and it won't disappear overnight.  You will also be in a good position to migrate existing code over to new framework.

Comment: @Peter **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/40980

Comment: @gnat : hmmm, I was indeed wrong, still the toilet bowl comparisation is a bad one  : I like programmers.SE a lot, I just seemed to be wrong about its scope.

Comment: A little late, but you can take a look at this post I wrote: http://yanivefraim.github.io/2015/05/27/be-ready-for-angular2-today-part1.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this nice [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2krqfe/so_should_i_continue_learning_angular/) topic for this subject.

**kogsworth**'s answer is really good and i agree with him.

> Of course it's worth it. The syntax might have changed substantially
>   between 1.3 and 2.0, but the fundamentals of the framework remain the
>   same. You'll have to learn to deal with dependency injection, two-way
>   binding, directives, services, filters, etc. What you're learning
>   today in tech will always become deprecated in the future, but the
>   time you spent now will help you learn/understand the next big thing.

And the main philosophy behind angular such as declarative style and testable code will not change. It is better to start learning now if you are coming from imperative front-end background.

Comment: Also remember that the paradigm shifts (if comming from most other javascript frameworks or vanilla) from imperative to declarative - which i think is the biggest challenge to overcome

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck, definitely. The main philosophy behind angular such as declarative style and testable code will not change.

Answer (score 1):

I've been giving angular talks in my city and one of the most discussed topics is the migration from angular1 which seems to scare a lot of people. Fear Not!
Angular1 is a mature framework that will be around for some time so it's worth learning it. If you wonder what should you learn first I'd say the new ECMAScript6 syntax and try to use it in you angular1 project, with that you have half of the migration done.
Of course moving to a new framework will require some work, that's why I created this [angular-migrate](https://github.com/olanod/angular-migrate) library with its [corresponding example](https://github.com/olanod/bookstore-example-ng1) to make it easier for people to code angular1 apps that will be future-proof.

About other frameworks, I recommend checking [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) by Rob Eisenberg, is a beautiful next generation framework very easy to learn.