# Developing a new Angular app - Preparing for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, angular

I'm developing a new AngularJS app and am wondering if there are things I can do to make migrating over to Angular 2 easier once it's out.

I'm excited about the changes that Igor presented at ngConf, but there seems like no roadmap to follow from the perspective of new projects getting started now.

With all the changes coming in the pipeline and the flexibility of a new app from scratch, some strategies for avoiding future landmines would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I start doing today to prepare for Angular 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682705/what-can-i-start-doing-today-to-prepare-for-angular-2-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning angularjs 1.3 , knowing that angular 2 will be released in 1 year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882789/learning-angularjs-1-3-knowing-that-angular-2-will-be-released-in-1-year)

Answer (score 2):

To be prepared for Angular 2 programming start learning TypeScript and get familiar with Web Components and Polymer.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but you can take a look at this post I wrote:
http://yanivefraim.github.io/2015/05/27/be-ready-for-angular2-today-part1.html